# Finding and replacing multiple matches in a single line with regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

I have a query regarding making multiple replacements within a string using a regular expression.

The platform is C#, so .NET's System.Text.RegularExpression implementation.

Let's say I have a string -- in this case, an XML fragment, but it could be any text at all, so no assumptions on the syntax:

```
<key val1="C:\SomeDir\SomePath\FOLDER1" val2="C:\SomeDir\SomePath\FOLDER2" />
```

I want to replace the last part of both of these paths -- let's say, change it to `FOLDER3`.

I currently have the expression `(C:\\SomeDir\\SomePath)(\\\w*\\)` which gives me two groups -- the first part of the path and the bit I want to replace.

I can use the replacement string `${1}\FOLDER3\` which properly replaces the part of the path I want to change.

However: this only works for the first match in the string.  So, `FOLDER1` will be replaced with `FOLDER3` but `FOLDER2` remains unchanged.

I thought I could apply the match/replace operation in a loop until the line no longer changed, but of course this doesn't work as the match regex always stops on the first match.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you post the code with which you try actually to replace it?

Comment: I think you should remove the last ``\\``. See [`(C:\\SomeDir\\SomePath)(\\\w*)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28C%3a%5c%5cSomeDir%5c%5cSomePath%29%28%5c%5c%5cw*%29&i=%3ckey+val1%3d%22C%3a%5cSomeDir%5cSomePath%5cFOLDER1%22+val2%3d%22C%3a%5cSomeDir%5cSomePath%5cFOLDER2%22+%2f%3e&r=%24%7b1%7d%5cFOLDER3%5c)

Answer (score -1):

Use the replace method of the regex. The replace method does replace all matches:

```
        string s = "<key val1=\"C:\\SomeDir\\SomePath\\FOLDER1\" val2=\"C:\\SomeDir\\SomePath\\FOLDER2\" />";
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"(C:\\SomeDir\\SomePath)(\\\w*)");
        string result = regex.Replace(s, x => x.Groups[1] + @"\FOLDER3");
```